# как записать кортеж в базу данных python

Tags: python, mysql

как записать кортеж в базу данных python mysql?

вот есть кортеж `tuple=('айфон',1000,'телефон','белый')`
как занести это в базу данных?

Comment: укажите на каком устройстве (Андроид/Windows) находится база данных, и что это за бд (dbf/sql lite/ms sql)

Comment: база данных на виндовс, mysql

Comment: ну занеси как строку. Ты же понимаешь, что БД нет такого типа записи, как кортеж, и придется кортеж куда-то конвертировать. Вот с этого и начинай.

Comment: Мне просто нужно добавить много кортежей

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

Answer (score 0):

В mysql нет такого типа данных как кортеж, если вам необходимо для каждой записи в таблице иметь столбец который ссылается на множество элементов, то лучше всего создать отдельную таблицу и связать ее с 1. Вот пример:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `product` (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    price INT NOT NULL,
    category ENUM('телефон', 'пк', 'чехол') NOT NULL,
    color VARCHAR(20) 
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `order` (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    count INT NOT NULL,
    product_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

В данном примере мы создаем таблицу заказов , в которой есть внешний ключ product_id, ссылающийся на первичный ключ таблицы product, которая заменит вам ваши кортежи